# Get nearby hospitals or fire stations based on your location?

Tags: geocoding, reverse-geocoding

Is it possible to calculate nearby hospitals or police or fire stations based on your location using `geocoding`? For instance: If I'm from place Chennai, India. Using `Geocoding` I need to get the list of all hospitals or police or fire stations nearby Chennai.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of the latitude and longitude of those hospitals and fire and police stations (as well as your own latitude and longitude), then sure it is possible.  The calculation of the distance between two points on a sphere (like Earth) is called the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).  You'd have to iterate over each one, calculating how far you were from it.  To speed things up, you might want to implement a geospatial index like the ones in [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing), [SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd434647.aspx), [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96630/sdo_index_query.htm), [SOLR](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpatialSearch), etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Is it possible through geocoding to determine nearby hospitals instead of loading all latitude and longitude on our own?

Comment: You either need to enter it yourself or purchase the data.  I doubt that there is any programmatic way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get nearby hospitals, police or fire stations etc based on your location by only using Google Places API though this API is paid so you need to have a billing account to use this API.